# Angular4 session handling

Tags: angular

I have a sailsjs backend for API's and I want to use Angular4 for my frontend. I was wondering, how can I handle sessions on Angular? I tried reading the documentation and was unable to come up with anything.

Specifically I need to be able to handle the login, log out, CSRF protection, etc. Is it possible to use Angular4 in Sails because Sails has all of that built in?

Comment: Yes, it is possible see my [Angular4-sails](https://github.com/rsthangavel/Angular-sails)

Answer (score 2):

As you want to use sails with Angular4 you may need add sails.io.js in your index.html as `<script src="/assets/sails.io/sails.io.js"></script>` ,keeping  your sails.io.js in assets/sails.io/ folder then import SailsModule and register the sails module in your in app.module.ts .Also add

`imports:[SailsModule.forRoot()]`

You may need to inject SailsService in the constructor and ngOnInit() call the connect() method of SailsService. Then you can use `request(options):Observable` method of SailsService to get the request(check http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/io-socket-request and check http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/sessions) with the help of `req.session` you can get session value and property.

Answer (score 2):

yes,
you can manage session by storing session details through a session service.

for best practice use google firebase auth feature which manages all the session, login and logout.

easy to implement...
free from google...
maintained by google....

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am working on an angular4 app whose backend API's are written in PHP and I am simply hitting them from my angular front end and getting the data, now in order to maintain session, I am simply using the SessionStorage and sometimes LocalStorage properties of javascript that allow us to save key/value pairs in a web browser.

ex: **sessionStorage.setItem("keyname", "value");**// to set

**var myvar=sessionStorage.getItem("keyname");**//to get

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this

**1. window.SessionStorage
2. Angular Service**

1.In your case you can use **SessionStroage** So whenever user is logged in, just set the data in sessionStroage like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem('userData', userObj);
```

and on logout

```
sessionStroage.clear();
```

2. Second Option is to put your data in a **globalService** So this service will contain in-app data and as soon as user is logged out, just clear the service Data.  Like this:-

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
login(){
  //initialize data here....
}

logout(){
   //remove your data....
 }
}
```

**Note: if browser tab is closed this data will be lost. if you want to recover this data then put it inside window.localStorage**